# Is there a way to apply conditional logic to ng-model-options within AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I want to only apply the debounce option if some value is true like so;

```
ng-model-options="isTrue && { debounce: 50 }"
```

Is there anyway to do this? The above does not work.

Have researched around and cannot find any information around this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question can be interpreted several different ways. Please be more specific and explain what you are needing to accomplish along with code representation . See [ask]

Comment: So what I am trying to achieve is to add the option to debounce an input with ng-model-options="{ debounce: 50 }"  but only when a value isTrue is true. I tried ng-model-options="isTrue && { debounce: 50 }" hoping that it would work in the same way as ng-style

Comment: Edit question and include all relevant details and html structure you are referring to. Also what have you tried? Couldn't you use variable for debounce value?